# Searching name using JS and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making name searching bar with JS and AJAX.
If write name on searching bar, only searched member must be shown.
And these are my code.

html:

```html
...
  <input type="text" id="searchName" name="searchName" placeholder="Search name..." onkeyup="nameFilter()" >
</div>          
<ul class="invite-list03"></ul> 
<ul id="memberList" class="member-list-group"></ul>
```

AJAX:

```js
for (let i in user.family) {
   let familyUserSn = user.family[i].familyUserSn;
   let familyMemberNm = user.family[i].familyMemberNm;
   let userProflPhotoCn = user.family[i].userProflPhotoCn;
   let memberCreatDt = user.family[i].memberCreatDt;

   let today = common_getTodayWithHyphen();
   let family;                          
   let hideDeleteBtn = '<div class="button-area"><button type="button" class="button-member-hide">hide</button><button type="button" class="button-member-delete" id="memberDeletePopUp">delete</button></div>';
                                            
// If today is invited day, show New icon up side of family member image
    if(memberCreatDt == today) {
        if(!userProflPhotoCn && userProflPhotoCn < 1) {
             family = '<li class="family" id="'+ familyUserSn+'"><div class="member-profile"><figure class="default-bg"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + DATA_NO_PROFILE + '" alt="profilePicture"></figure><label class="new">N</label></div><p class="member-name">'+familyMemberNm+'</p>'+ hideDeleteBtn + '</li>';
       } else {
       family = '<li class="family" id="'+ familyUserSn+'"><div class="member-profile"><figure class="default-bg"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + userProflPhotoCn + '" alt="profilePicture"></figure><label class="new">N</label></div><p class="member-name">'+familyMemberNm+'</p>'+ hideDeleteBtn + '</li>';                               
       }
   } else {
       if(!userProflPhotoCn && userProflPhotoCn < 1) {
          family = '<li class="family" id="'+ familyUserSn+'"><div class="member-profile"><figure class="default-bg"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + DATA_NO_PROFILE + '" alt="profilePicture"></figure></div><p class="member-name">'+familyMemberNm+'</p>'+ hideDeleteBtn + '</li>';
       } else {
           family = '<li class="family" id="'+ familyUserSn+'"><div class="member-profile"><figure class="default-bg"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + userProflPhotoCn + '" alt="profilePicture"></figure></div><p class="member-name">'+familyMemberNm+'</p>'+ hideDeleteBtn + '</li>';
                            }
       }      
// append to memberList 
       $("#memberList").append(family); 
   }        
// I am first member of list
$(".family").first().click();
```

JS:

```js
function nameFilter() {
    let searchNameSave = $('#searchName').val(); 
    if(searchNameSave.length > 0) {
        $("#memberList").html("");
        $("ul#memberList > li > .member-name:contains('" + searchNameSave + "')").parent().show();      
    }
}
```

What should I write in javascript? Now it doesn't working.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What I can see is that you clear contents of your '#memberList' and then you try to access its child nodes. What I would suggest is simply hide all elements and then show the matching ones. You definitely must get rid of the .html("") as that will remove everything and the next line cannot work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are a few things you need to do

1. Ajax get source information
2. Filter the source data according to the search criteria
3. Remove the old data and replace the filtered data

You can set your code according to this idea

The following is an example of using jquery-ui + ajax + autocomplete for your reference

```js
$("#queryname").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/ajax/data/objects_salary.txt",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                const matcher = new RegExp(request.term, "i");
                const datas = data['data'];
                response($.map(datas, function(item) {
                    if (matcher.test(item.name)) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='queryname' name='queryname' placeholder='Enter some text' />
```